# How to find the difference between these two times 06:34:23 and 02:45:55

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

User have the option to enter times.Here is an example 
find the difference between these two times  06:34:23 and 02:45:55.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)** to parse the dates to milliseconds since epoc and find the difference.

```
// gives you the difference in seconds
var diff = (Date.parse("1-1-1 06:34:23") - Date.parse("1-1-1 02:45:55")) / 1000;
```

*Note that I've given a dummy date of 1-1-1 above to make the date-format sane.*

Comment: Yep, this is the best solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + "06:34:23 ");
    var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + "02:45:55.");
    var hourdif = timeEnd.getHours() - timeStart.getHours();
    var mindif = timeEnd.getMinutes() - timeStart.getMinutes();
```